# CString to std::cout

Tags: c++, visual-c++

How to print CString to console? Trying this code, but got something like pointer is printed.

```
..
#include <iostream>
#include <atlstr.h>

using namespace std;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    CString a= "ddd";
    cout<<a.GetString();
}

Output 00F56F0
```

Answer (score 6):

Use following :

```
std::wcout << a.GetString();
```

Answer (score 4):

Use **wcout** to print CString to console:

```
CString cs("Hello");
wcout << (const wchar_t*) cs << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

> How to print CString to console? Trying this code, but got something
>   like pointer is printed.

My apologies. I was not finished and got interrupted. Apparently you have to convert to a temporary CStringA (otherwise it is wide string format i.e wcout). I did not realise this until I read your message (again):

```
std::ostream& operator << ( std::ostream& os, const CString& str )
{
  if( str.GetLength() > 0 )  //GetLength???
  {
    os << CStringA( str ).GetString();
  }
  return os;
}
```

You could as suggested of course just use wcout:

```
std::ostream& operator << ( std::wostream& os, const CString& str )
{
  if( str.GetLength() > 0 )  //GetLength???
  {
    os << CStringA( str ).GetString();
  }
  return os;
}
```

Then use like this:

```
std::wcout << str << std::endl;
```